# Perform Segue with Identifier from ViewDidAppear not working

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, viewdidappear

I have a view for a Terms and Conditions page for my app that I am trying to get to appear modally the first time the app opens. I know that the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method is being called at the correct time but the corresponding view is never loaded. `viewDidLoad` in the future view controller is never called. Also the segue identifiers match correctly as far as I can tell. This results in the appearance of a blank black screen.

[image: Blank Screen]

```
   override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    print("Here")

    if !defaults.boolForKey("hasLaunchedBefore"){

        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "hasLaunchedBefore")
        setSettingsForFirstTime()

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("firstTime", sender: self)

    }

}
```

The highlighted ViewController is where the segue starts and it should end at the other navigation controller and consequently the Terms and Conditions page, which never loads. The top ViewController's navigation controller is the entry point for the app.
[image: Storyboard]

Comment: You have a strange scheme in storyboard, NavigationController should be the first,  for your TableViewController you need embed in with NavigationController and then make segue from TableView to next ViewController

Comment: The TableViewController is embedded in a navigation controller not seen in the picture. The terms and Conditions ViewController is embedded in a separate ViewController because this allows me to give the view a navbar while presenting it modally. I have done this before and it has not been problematic and I don't see why it would cause a problem this way.

Answer (score -1):

That's because you have navigation controller in the middle 
You can go past it in your prepare for segue and make the view invisible before initiating the segue to show show straight to terms and conditions view

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.view.hidden = true
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(true)

    if !defaults.boolForKey("hasLaunchedBefore"){

        defaults.setBool(true, forKey: "hasLaunchedBefore")
        setSettingsForFirstTime()

        self.performSegueWithIdentifier("firstTime", sender: self)
    }
    else { self.view.hidden = false }
}



override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "Id" {
            if let navVc = segue.destinationViewController is UINavigationController {
                if let contentVc = (self as! UINavigationController).visibleViewController {
                     //do preparation
                }
            } 
        }
   }
```

Comment: I'm not doing anything in prepare for segue, can you elaborate?

Comment: You need to have prepare for segue, I'll add how to do that if you don't know

Comment: I've used the prepare for segue method before, but I figured since there is no information I need to pass to the other viewController I didn't need to do that. If I don't want to pass information through is there anything I still need to do?